# too expensive for John to buy it

Tags: pronouns, redundancy

Is it okay to include "it" in the following sentences?

> a. The car is too expensive for John to buy **it**.

> b. The car is cheap enough for John to buy **it**.

Comment: Casual/careless use of English. Common in informal speech.

Comment: If "for John" is removed, can "it" be retained?

Comment: _It_ is unnecessary. Indeed, "The car is too expensive for John" would be understood to mean 'for him to buy'.

Comment: Yes, it can be included or left out, and so can "for John," if the context implies it. (For that matter, so could "to buy.") It's not "careless," or even necessarily casual, to have implied parts of speech.

Comment: A car could be too expensive to insure, rent, lease, hire, or run, as well as buy.

Comment: Is "The car is too expensive to buy it" correct?

Comment: @Apollyon - no. Lose the final 'it'.